# PHP FPM not serving latest code changes

Tags: php, php-7.1

When I load the site, the old JS/CSS builds load. SQS queues are using the latest code after restarting supervisor, but when jobs are dispatched they contain references from the old code so the queues break.

I look at the code in VIM on the server and it's the right code, but it's not what PHP FPM is serving. PHP CLI seems to have it right.

I've tried:

- Redeploying using Envoyer.
- Clearing all server side and client side caches
- Restarting PHP FPM using `sudo -S service php7.1-fpm reload`
- Restarting all supervisor workers.
- Disabling OPCache.

Nothing makes it use the right code for FPM.

What could be going on here?

PHP 7.1

Comment: My cents on the browser cache. Try: Show source of html, click link to js-resource. Refresh. Ok?

Comment: I did a hard reload on the browser side and cleared the cache. The JS resource has the wrong build number. Server side, the PHP code in the controller is dispatching legacy code from an old commit when the client side requests an operation. So this isn't just a browser caching issue.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an Nginx misconfiguration on the new server.

The line....

```
root /home/user/site/public;
```

...needed to point to `current` to work properly with Envoyer:

```
root /home/user/site/current/public;
```